# How to modify a 2d list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I a beginner in python and I'm struggling in a code to modify a 2d list in a loop 'for'

Here is my code

````
```
def test() :
    L=[[0]*2]*2
    for i in range (2) :
        for j in range (2) :
            L[j][i]=1
            print(L)
```
````

And it returns to me ... :

````
```
test()
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]

```
````

It is normaly supposed to work ^^
Thanks for your help !

Comment: What result did you expect instead?

Comment: sorry ! I expected : [[1, 0], [0, 0]]
[[1, 1], [0, 0]]
[[1, 1], [1, 0]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]

Comment: thanks ! I didn't see that post, I'm sorry !